# Restricting Display of WMS Hosted on Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have several WMS layers that I am hosting on Geoserver that cover the entire state of Iowa. I would like to restrict these layers to only show a certain area, in this case, specific counties. Is this something that can be achieved through setting the bounding boxes to only cover my counties? Not sure where to start.

Comment: possibly, or you could add a filter to the layer - really need more info as to types of layers/data store

Comment: You can use SLD to set min and max scales.